# Set focus on new page in Tizen Caph 3.0 Angular

Tags: angularjs, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'am developing Tizen TV app using Caph 3.0 library.
And i can't set focus manually when i relocating to the new page.
For example i have page with next code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="" ui-sref='home' >Movies</a>
<a href="" ui-sref='series'>Series</a>
```

When i clicking on Series link - new page with next code appears

```
<a href="" focusable on-focused='seriesCtrl.focusedItem($event)' id='1'>test element1</a>
<a href="" focusable on-focused='seriesCtrl.focusedItem($event)'id='2'>test element1</a>
<a href="" focusable on-focused='seriesCtrl.focusedItem($event)' id='3'>test    element1</a>
```

But i lost the focus. I can't navigating on that new page using arrow Keys (emulator)
I tried set focus manually using focusController.focus() but it does not helped me.
I using ControllerAs syntax.

**Controller** of new page

```
focusController.focus(document.getElementById('1'));

console.log(focusController.getCurrentFocusItem()); ----- In this place console shows that focus still on Series link from previous page

vm.focusedItem = function ($event) {
 console.log($event.currentTarget)
}
```

Where i made a mistake?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolved. Thanks to CAPH support.

Try

```
App.controller("DetailPageCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'focusController', 'FocusUtil', function($rootScope, $scope, focusController, FocusUtil) {
function initFocus() {
                        $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
                            FocusUtil.isElement($('#1')) && focusController.focus($('#1'));
                        });
                    }
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
                        console.log("jj apply async $viewContentLoaded");
                        initFocus();
                    });

....... }])
```

P:S: Also check ng-controller does not belong to < body > tag